# How to Merge Three Lists and retrieve each list with key Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, datatable

I want to Merge three List and retrieve each list with a key

```
List1 =[0.1,0.2,0.3,.....];
List2 =[0.5,0.10,6.0,......];
List3 =[1,2,3,.....]
```

I want to retrieve the All Lists  into a dynamic Data Table Like

```
Table Row => [ list1[index] , list2[index] , list3[index]  ]
```

Comment: Have you tried `var table = [List1, List2, List3]` ?

Comment: No i want to genrate a table with three lists

Comment: Row Data 1st cell = list 1[index] & Row Data 2nd cell = list2 [index] & Row Data 3rd cell = list3[index]

Comment: length of all list is from user input

Comment: Now i have 3 lists with user input but how can i retrieve 3 lists in data table

Comment: how to retrieve in table ??